# Passing multiple xml to stored procedure and retrieving xml attribute

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, xml, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which reads some Ids and gets the value of XMLs associated with those ids from the table.

```
USE [Database]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[GetLetterIssueTcm]    Script Date: 03/31/2014 12:07:02 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetLetterIssueTcm]

@LetterIds varchar(5000)

AS 

Declare @SQL VarChar(1000)

select @SQL = 'Select content from component_presentations where publication_id =  80
and template_id = 41064 and component_id in (' + @LetterIds +')'    

Exec ( @SQL)
```

LetterIds is a comma separated string of ids like "55773,52663" The contents returned by this Stored procedure contains XMLs for each LetterId. The XML looks like:

```
<letterIssue>
    <Date>2010-12-01T00:00:00</Date>
    <Items>
        <Item id="tcm:80-74757"></Item>
        <Item id="tcm:80-74760"></Item>
        <Item id="tcm:80-74766"></Item>
        <Item id="tcm:80-74770"></Item>
        <Item id="tcm:80-74772"></Item>
    </Items>
</letterIssue>
```

Now I want to create a virtual table which has the Letter Id in one column and associated Item Ids in second row from the xml of that letter Id. Something like:

```
LetterId           Item_Id
55773             tcm:80-74757
55773             tcm:80-74760
```

This can be done in same stored procedure or I don't mind passing the output of this stored procedure (multiple xmls) to another and then  retrieving the item ids associated with it. So How do I process the multiple xmls and find the item ids from them??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
select component_id, i.i.value('@id', 'varchar(100)') as item
from component_presentations t
outer apply t.content.nodes('/letterIssue[1]/Items[1]/Item')i(i)
where publication_id =  80 and template_id = 41064 and
    component_id in (55773,66884)
```

P.S. What would you do if one day you'll get `@LetterIds = '55773;drop table component_presentations'`?

Comment: Can you help me understand this. I could not understand anything you have done. New to sql.

Comment: Outer apply multiples every record by number of found `Item` elements. So you get many small xmls looking like this: `<Item id="tcm:80-74757"></Item>`. Then saying `value` you take data from these small xmls.

Comment: Getting error: Msg 9506, Level 16, State 1, Procedure GetPublicationAndNewsLetterIssueTcm, Line 10
The XMLDT method 'nodes' can only be invoked on columns of type xml.

Comment: Maybe `content` column's data type is not xml? If you don't want or cannot change the data type of `content` column, then replace `t.content.nodes` with `t.cast(content as xml).nodes`.

Comment: See `.../Item')i(i)`. First `i` is alias of nodes we've got. Second one is column name in these nodes.

Comment: Yup. Got the desired output now. Thanks.